# New version of iOS app upload to itunes connect : Invalid bundle

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, app-store, appstore-approval

I have developed a new version of our application in Xamarin Studio.

I am trying to upload the new version but as soon as it got uploaded it says Invalid Build. I received the email from apple store team:

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   "XYZ". To process your delivery, the following issues must be
>   corrected:
>
> This bundle is invalid - The Info.plist file for
>   /Payload/XYZ.iOS.app/GoogleAuthUtilities.framework is missing or could
>   not be read.
>
> Invalid Bundle - The bundle at
>   '/Payload/XYZ.iOS.app/GoogleAuthUtilities.framework' does not contain
>   a bundle executable.
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the
>   corrected binary.

I have already tried to reloaded the support packages and recreate the archive.

Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay! So the problem was in the Google Component. I was using component with version 4.0.0 and that's what the reason behind the problem. I got the update from Github for version 4.0.1 and it is still not available in the Xamarin Nuget package, so whoever wants solve this problem, he has to download the git project and make the changes in order to get the updated google component.

Please refer [this](https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/issues/45) link for more information.

Answer (score 0):

For me, what worked was to install the packages from NuGet where I was able to select the version 3.0.1 of GoogleSignIn so my app was approved again by Apple;

Sorry for English

Thaks and advance!

Comment: yes, one can download the old version and get the things working. And, install the new version when its available.